# Spark EMR Exception when Fetching Delta Data from S3

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr, delta

I am encountering a SparkException when attempting to fetch Delta data from an S3 location and submitting a Spark job on Amazon EMR. The error message is as follows:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Unable to create database default as failed to create its directory hdfs:///user/spark/warehouse
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.InMemoryCatalog.liftedTree1$1(InMemoryCatalog.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.InMemoryCatalog.createDatabase(InMemoryCatalog.scala:118)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog(SharedState.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.isDatabaseExistent$1(SharedState.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.globalTempViewManager$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:201)
```

**Context:**

- The Spark job works fine on a standalone machine but encounters this issue when submitted on EMR.
- The job involves fetching Delta data from an S3 location.
- The directory mentioned in the error (hdfs:///user/spark/warehouse) seems related to Spark's warehouse directory.

I'm seeking guidance on how to resolve this SparkException on EMR. Are there specific configurations or settings on EMR that I might be missing? Any insights into debugging this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Below is code snippet of how I am retrieving delta data from S3 Location. The same code snippet is working on standalone program.

```
Dataset<Row> resultDs = sparkSession.sql("select * from delta.`s3://dev-ohio/anshuman` as temp");
```

**Note : S3 URI is an arbitary value.**

Comment: Which EMR or Spark version are you using? Looks the issue was in Spark 
2.0.1, and they fixed it in 2.0.2 and 2.1.0. Please see ticket [SPARK-17810](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17810) "Default spark.sql.warehouse.dir is relative to local FS but can resolve as HDFS path".